# how to search record based on date submitted in form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to search record in mysql based on date which is submitted hidden field in a form, but I haven't got any results from DB with given date, I know there is a record with the same date.

I have a following code:

```
$id = $_POST['pid']; //hidden field in form with sample value 1
$d = $_POST['d']; // hidden field in form with  sample value 2014-12-17 18:25:58
$ch = $con->query('SELECT * FROM '.PATDMBILL.' WHERE pid='.$id.' AND pfid=0 AND date="'.$d.'"');
```

In DB date column is current time-stamp.

When I assign $d to this value '2014-12-17 18:25:58' it works but from submitting form it will not work.

So Where I am making a mistake ?

I hope I have cleared my situation properly.

Comment: What does `var_dump($d);` say? Is it already quoted? Because you're putting quotes around it in the query as well

Comment: "SELECT * FROM PATDMBILL WHERE pid=".$id." AND pfid=0 AND date=".date('Y-m-d H:i:S',strtotime($d))

Comment: "it will not work?"  What kind of failure are you having? Zero rows returned? Invalid query?

Comment: **WARNING**: Your code is open to SQL injection hacks. **BAD!**. Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @KEK var_dump($d) is string '2014-12-17 19:05:36' (length=19)

Comment: @OllieJones I am getting zero rows from query.

Comment: @jessehouwing its a sample code actually I am using bind method of mysqli

Comment: @Bhavin Pfew :). It might be a good idea to mention that in the question. People might pick this up as a "proper solution" otherwise.

Comment: Do you have a entry in DB with date `'2014-12-17 19:05:36'` then? Since you said `'2014-12-17 18:25:58'` worked

Comment: @KEK yes I have a entry in DB with date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the code:

```
$id = $_POST['pid'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM '.PATDMBILL.' WHERE pid='.$id.' AND pfid=0 AND date="'.$d.'"';
echo $query;

$ch = $con->query($query);
```

You will then be able to see if the query is actually formatted properly and fix any obvious issues. Unfortunately there isn't enough information to say what the solution is, but you should be able to copy and paste the echoed 'query' and paste it into the tool you use to build queries (eg phpmyadmin or sequel pro)

Comment: I have echoed query as suggested and found this in query:SELECT * FROM patdmbill WHERE pid=1 AND pfid=0 AND date="", So its look like there is no value in $d but I also echoed $_POST['d'] which have desired value. So Where I am mistaking ?

Comment: please check my comment above, my previous comment was about mysqli error. thanks

Comment: What happens when you do $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.PATDMBILL.' WHERE pid='.$id.' AND pfid=0 AND date="'. $_POST['d'] .'"';

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be occurring because of the time 18:25:58 . You can change the database field from timestamp to date and pass only date from $d using `strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $d));`

Comment: I can not change DB field to only date, I need timestamp in my application to work it properly.